# ¿Cómo actualizar registros de una tabla que contengan la misma fecha en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Un saludo, estoy realizando un *CRUD*, en **MVC**.
Para ello utilizo **php**, **js** y **mysql**.

Intento Actualizar la etapa a todos los registros que contengan **la misma fecha** en la tabla.

Este es mi procedimiento:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_CAMBIAR_ENGORDE`(IN FECHA DATE)
UPDATE cerdos_reproducidos SET
eta_id = 3
WHERE cerp_fechafinaletapa = FECHA AND cerdos_reproducidos.mov_id = 1
    AND
    cerdos_reproducidos.eta_id=2
```

La fecha a la cual aplicará el `update` se la envío desde mi modal.

Me dice que la ejecución es exitosa, pero no realiza ningún cambio.

También he ejecutado el procedimiento desde mi gestor, e igual me dice exitoso, pero tampoco realiza ningún cambio.

Comment: si, deben de cumplir las 3 condiciones, que estén en movimiento = 1 , estén en etapa = 2 y que la fecha_final sean igual a la fecha que le envió desde el modal

Comment: los registros siempre inician en movimiento = 1,

Comment: la etapa siempre empieza en etapa = 1, se le definen (ejemplo: 10 dias) para pasar a la siguiente etapa, al llegar al ultimo dia se debe de cambiar a etapa = 2. se le vuelven a definir cuantos días estará en etapa 2 y posterior pasar a etapa = 3.

Comment: lo que busco es lograr cambiar la etapa a todos los registros disponibles de ese día y no estarlos actualizando uno por uno.

Comment: las condiciones se cumplen, porque tengo un listado donde me muestra los registros con esas condiciones. que sean movimiento 1 y etapa 2

Comment: Sería bueno que nos mostraras la estructura de la tabla que quieres actualizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para chequear que registros se van a actualizar puedes ejecutar una query con el mismo WHERE:

```
SELECT *
FROM cerdos_reproducidos
WHERE cerp_fechafinaletapa = FECHA AND cerdos_reproducidos.mov_id = 1 AND cerdos_reproducidos.eta_id=2
```

El update lo podrías hacer ejecutando directamente la query UPDATE, sin necesidad de crear a un procedimiento.

Chequea que la fecha que le estás pasando al procedimiento sea correcta.

Revisa los logs de MySql para cerciorarte de que no haya fallado nada.

Para llamar al procedimiento:

```
CALL `SP_CAMBIAR_ENGORDE`(FECHA);
```

Comment: gracias tu comentario me ayudo, a ver que es lo que estaba haciendo mal

Comment: Listo ya lo he resuelto, estaba enviando la fecha equivocada, por eso no me estaba actualizando. muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios, me ayudaron a ver que estaba haciendo mal. les agradezco. 

Al final el procedimiento si esta bien.

Comment: De nada! Me alegra que lo hayas resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente te esté dando ok, porque los filtros que están aplicando en el where no estén dando resultados. Prueba a meter en el procedimiento un SELECT con las mismas condiciones que el UPDATE para ver qué conjunto de datos te saldrían para actualizar.